# How to calculate percentage for two different values?

Tags: calculus, percentile

I have two data one is like$=75$ and second data is dislike$=127$, both values are counted separately. But i need to show percentage of this.

For example $40\%$ likes and $60\%$ dislikes for the above something like.

I know to calculate percentage for single value $(\%/100)*x$ but for the above i don't have idea.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likes: $\quad\dfrac{\text{total number of likes}}{\text{total number of those answering}}\;=\;\dfrac{75}{75+127}\times 100\% \approx 37.13\%$.

Dislikes: $\dfrac{\text{total number of dislikes}}{\text{total number of those answering}} \;=\;\dfrac{127}{75 + 127} \times 100\%\approx 62.87\%$

Comment: Thank +1. I really don't have much knowledge in maths except simple % percentage calculation. Can you refer me a way where i can start to learn and improve my ability to clear aptitude.

Comment: Sure: Are you familiar with Khan's Academy? I'll see if I can find a quick link to this material. See for example, a whole [sequence of tutorials](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-seventh-grade-math/cc-7th-fractions-decimals/cc-7th-percent-word-problems/v/solving-percent-problems): they're incremented from "beginner" to increasing levels of difficulty. Khan's academy is on-line, and entirely free!

Comment: No i don't know, also it would be helpful if you refer any simple books to learn

Comment: @amWhy: So nicely formatted! +1

Comment: If there are no people answering, this is undefined (or unless in your case 0/0 equals to 0, both would be 0% instead of 50%

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to know the total number of votes (both likes and dislikes). This is $75 + 127 = 202$. So now we can say:

> There are 202 votes total and 75 of them are 'like'-votes. What is the percentage of 'like'-votes?

I hope you can tell that the answer to this is the answer you're looking for. At this point, more or less each teacher and textbook have their own approach and explanation. However, they all end up, in one way or another, with performing the division
$$
\frac{75}{202}\approx 0.371
$$
Multiply with $100\%$, and the answer is $37.1\%$ likes. The rest ($100\% - 37.1\% = 62.9\%$) are the dislikes.

Comment: Can you refer me any book to start? I don't know which topic is basic. @Arthur